# app submission for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I read news that for game submission for wp7, Microsoft have given a date 14june 2011, is there any deadline for App submission also to the MarketPlace. can some body please tell me about that?!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding. Please read that news:
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/news/Submissions_End_June_14

There is a subimission deadline for the Dream.Build.Play competition, but that has nothing to do with the general submission of apps and games to the wp7 marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

The deadline is june 30th 2011

Comment: can u please send me any official link where i can get the full detail about this,thanks